# Send OTP via email in Keycloak

Tags: keycloak, one-time-password, password-less

I want to use Keycloak to implement SSO but I noticed that there is no email OTP embedded in Keycloak. How do I sent OTP through email in Keycloak?

I want the OTP to be provided not only via GoogleAuthenticator or FreeOTP app but also via email.

Is it possible to do it with Keycloak?

Comment: You can write your own extension. Look for the class `OTPFormAuthenticator`.

Comment: If you still need one please visit this link.
https://gitlab.com/niroj.adhikary/keycloak-email-otp/-/tree/master

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, you need to new authenticator provider.
The Server Development part of the Keycloak reference documentation contains additional resources and examples for developing custom Keycloak extensions.
https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html

or you can use this email 2fa otp keycloak provider

https://github.com/mesutpiskin/keycloak-2fa-email-authenticator